# 3ware 97504i - Disk mappings/UUIDs change on reboot

Tags: raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware 9750-4i with 36 drives running (4 in RAID 10, rest individual drives, i.e JBOD).

When I reboot, all the drives except for the RAID 10 array, have their UUIDs changed on reboot (it seems random, as I've rebooted a few times and each time it was a completely different UUID). This causes me to manually go through 32 drives, figure out where it should *really* be mapped and remount it there.

I haven't found anything online even related to this issue, and I'm really new to RAID cards in general. Is there some sort of setting I might be missing? Or maybe something with my kernel causing this (again, I'm not very knowledgeable about kernels either)

Edit: Running Debian 7.6 64bit.

Note I've limited output to just the first few drives since they're all the same.

**fdisk -l**

```
root@server:~# fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 8000.0 GB, 7999978471424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 972608 cylinders, total 15624957952 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdd: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sde'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sde: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdf'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdf: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdh'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdh: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdi'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdi: 4000.0 GB, 3999989235712 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486304 cylinders, total 7812478976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdi1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

**And df -h**

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   37G   11G   24G  32% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    13G  167M   13G   2% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid>   37G   11G   24G  32% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                    26G  528K   26G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2                                               7.2T  695G  6.2T  10% /mount/sda
/dev/sdaf1                                              7.3T  1.7T  5.3T  24% /mount/sdaf
cgroup                                                   64G     0   64G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc1                                               3.6T  1.2T  2.3T  35% /mount/sdc
/dev/sdd1                                               3.6T  1.6T  1.9T  46% /mount/sdd
/dev/sde1                                               3.6T  1.5T  2.0T  44% /mount/sde
/dev/sdh1                                               3.6T  2.0T  1.5T  59% /mount/sdh
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=016efca3-ff51-4c3f-8fb4-6374e732168f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=b79fed8c-a61d-4b19-a5b6-6bb4ec7c60e5 /mount/sda ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=e82eefed-1017-471f-b243-90f812804d66 /mount/sdz ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=472c2b9c-ea28-40e2-a87f-872139c1efaa /mount/sdb ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=fd0d963b-79d8-489e-8ce4-11bc4bf947af /mount/sdc ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=fd5ddc4b-1cd4-4c39-828e-47c459f7c029 /mount/sdd ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=71642e4f-dc44-4895-aebb-a9130cc88cbb /mount/sde ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
UUID=cf9fd919-6f7c-4be5-a1d1-766aef130878 /mount/sdf ext4    noatime,usrquota,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=120,nobh,barrier=0 0       2
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Debian 7.6 64bit

Comment: Are you trying to use ZFS? Hadoop? Ceph? What's the reason for the multiple individual drives in this installation? Can you post the outputs of `df -h` and maybe part of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Nothing special like ZFS/Hadoop. They're just mounted to individual directories. Added some information to the original post.

Comment: And your /etc/fstab? Are you mounting by disk UUID? By device path?

Comment: Added - I was mounting via device path (i.e /dev/sda) then changed to UUID thinking they shouldn't change, but ended up with the same problem

Comment: How do you know the UUIDs are changing? Is there any pattern? This isn't normal behavior.

Comment: I recorded the UUIDs and then rebooted (several times) - They were different again. However I had to reboot because of some lockup problems this morning, and oddly, the UUIDs were the same.. I'm not inclined to test it again at the moment though.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to the problem you can use LVM/labels to mount the drives with, instead their names. This isn't the solution to the original issue, but I hope this can eliminate the consequences.